# C++ List Iterator Restart actions if List changes

Tags: c++, list, hash, iterator

I have list of char's which my program iterates through. As my for loop checks each character, I apply a number of tests.

What I need to do, is if one of the tests changes the list (i.e. the Hash is changed), restart the tests again from the start. Only if all the test are completed can my 'for' loop continue to the next character.

A do-while loop could possibly work but i'm having trouble.

In the example, the result should be "ty", not "ttty".

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <list>

     using namespace std;

     void testOne();
     void testTwo();
     void print();
     unsigned short calculateHash(list<char> &charList);

     list<char> charList;
     list<char>::iterator iter;
     list<char>::iterator iter2;

     int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        charList.push_back('t');
        charList.push_back('t');
        charList.push_back('t');
        charList.push_back('t');
        charList.push_back('t');
        charList.push_back('x');

        print();
        cout << "Hash = " << calculateHash(charList) << '\n';

        for(iter = charList.begin(), iter2 = ++charList.begin(); iter != charList.end(); ++iter, ++iter2) {


           unsigned short hash;
           hash = calculateHash(charList);

           // if one of the tests changes the list
           // start the tests again...

           //while (hash == calculateHash(charList))

           // loop here.
           testOne();
           testTwo();

        }
        print();
        cout << "Hash = " << calculateHash(charList) << '\n';
     }

     void testOne() {
        if (*iter == *iter2) {
           charList.erase(iter2);
           iter2 = iter;
           ++iter2;
        }
     };

     void testTwo() {
        if (*iter == 'x')
           (*iter) = 'y';

     };

     void print() {
        list<char>::iterator it;
        for(it = charList.begin(); it != charList.end(); it++)
           cout << *it;

        cout << '\n';
     };

     unsigned short calculateHash(list<char> &charList) {
        unsigned short shift, hash = 0;
        list<char>::const_iterator itr;
        for (itr = charList.begin(); itr != charList.end(); itr++) {
           hash ^= *itr;
           shift = (hash & 15);
           hash = (hash << shift) | (hash >> (16 - shift));
        }
        return hash;
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a while loop something like this

```
iter = charList.begin();
while (iter != charList.end()) {
    hash = computeHash();
    testOne();
    newhash = computeHash();
    if (hash != newHash) {
        iter = charList.begin();
        continue;
    }
    /* do the same for all other tests*/
    iter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as a for loop:

```
bool reset;
for (auto it = charList.begin(); 
     it != charList.end(); 
     it = (reset ? charList.begin() : it+1) )
{
    const unsigned short hash = calculateHash(charList);

    // loop here.
    // Note both functions need to return true if the loop should be
    // restarted.  If testOne returns true, testTwo will not be executed
    // (which is just as well, as the list has changed under it's feet.
    reset = testOne() || testTwo();
}
```